# Auto destruct variables after loop scope-end

Tags: python

Unlike other languages like c, c++ where the scope of the variables stay inside the loop. Eg.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    do stuff;
}

i+=1  // raises error as i is not initialised.
```

where as the same code works in python

```
for i in range(5)
    do stuff

i+=1  # doesn't raise error as i is initialised.
```

Though this can be helpful at times, sometimes it is a pain as even though rarely I use variable names like `i, key, value` yet again in the code after the loop without facing any explicit error.

Is there a more pythonic way than using `del i` after the loop to avoid the above issues?

EDIT: This question has been marked duplicate of [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/4982729) which I had seen ages ago. That thread describes how scoping works in python whereas my question is totally different. Please unmark this as a duplicate.

Comment: just wrap it in a function

Comment: If your methods are complex enugh that you worry about this, perhaps the fix is to write simpler methods.

Comment: @kevinkayaks wrapping every loop in a function seems a bit too untidy, isn't it? anything pythonic will be appreciated. :)

Comment: Is `del i` really "unpythonic?"

Comment: The pythonic way is that variables can be used after th loop, IMHO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short description of the scoping rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: Python does not have blocks scops

Comment: proposal for for-loop variable scope https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2008-October/002109.html

Comment: Python isn't C or C++.

Comment: Every comment is missing the line - `Is there a more pythonic way than using del i after the loop to avoid the above issues?` . I would gladly accept the answer which says - "no there is no such way" without being rude, if that is true.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, list comprehension may be one answer...?

```
[print(i) for i in range(5)]
print(i)

>> 0
1
2
3
4

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-598b4fd0c0c5> in <module>()
1 [print(i) for i in range(5)]
----> 2 print(i)

NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Comment: I am aware of list comprehensions. My loops are not nearly as simple as this.